# How to use code completion into Eclipse with OpenCV

Tags: linux, eclipse, opencv, code-completion

I would like to make work the source code completion for Opencv 2.3 on Eclipse.
How can i do that?
Programs work fine but the completion [ctrl+space] appears: "No default proposals".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For C/C++:

1. Use CDT in Eclipse
2. In your project root directory, create the project's Makefiles:

   cmake -G 'Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles'
3. Import the project using *Eclipse->File->Import->General->Existing Projects*
4. Enjoy code completion using *Ctrl-Space*

For Python

1. Install PyDev
2. In Eclipse Navigate to... **Window->Preferences->PyDev->Interpreters**
3. Configure PyDev, selecting the Python interpreter to be used
4. Add */usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages* *(or other valid path(s))* to the System Libraries
5. Add cv (or cv2) to the *Forced builtins*
6. Enjoy code using *Ctrl-Space*

Comment: Thank you so much for this!  I've been looking for this for hours.  However, I didn't need to add the dist-packages folder for some reason.

Comment: @TH. I am new to Python and I don't understand the step number 3. I previously added _/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages_ to External Libs in my project but ctrl+space still doesn't work.

Comment: Python works and it doesn't... it completes when I use the cv2 or cv2.cv namespace, but if I have (for ex.) an array of images in a class that I then pass to a function and loop through, accessing the image variable doesn't know it's an image and the completion list is empty. Is this surmountable or just a general problem with dynamic typing? I added the forced built-in, but that didn't help and doesn't seem required.

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to use python's opencv I've found

```
from cv2.cv import *
```

in the file site-packages/cv.py, for this case I've had to use an import of:

```
import cv2.cv as cv

#instead of

import cv
```

to get the code completion to work.