# What is different between all these OpenCV Python interfaces?

Tags: python, opencv

There are

- [`opencv`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/introduction.html) (the library from the OpenCV guys),
- [`cv`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/cookbook.html) (the old library from the OpenCV guys) and
- [`pyopencv`](https://code.google.com/p/pyopencv/) with its predecessor [`ctypes-opencv`](http://code.google.com/p/ctypes-opencv/).

What are the main differences and which one should I use?

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Officially, OpenCV releases two types of Python interfaces, `cv` and `cv2`.

**cv:**

I started working on `cv`. In this, all OpenCV data types are preserved as such. For example, when loaded, images are of format `cvMat`, same as in C++.

For array operations, there are several functions like `cvSet2D`, `cvGet2D`, etc. And some discussions say, they are slower.

For imageROI, you need special functions like `cvSetImageROI`.

If you find contours, `cvSeq` structures are returned which is not so good to work with compared to Python lists or NumPy arrays.

(And I think, soon its development will be stopped. Earlier, there was only `cv`. Later, OpenCV came with both `cv` and `cv2`. Now, there in the latest releases, there is only the `cv2` module, and `cv` is a subclass inside `cv2`. You need to call `import cv2.cv as cv` to access it.)

**cv2:**

And the latest one is `cv2`. In this, everything is returned as `NumPy` objects like `ndarray`  and `native Python` objects like `lists`,`tuples`,`dictionary`, etc. So due to this NumPy support, you can do any numpy operation here. `NumPy` is a highly stable and fast array processing library.

For example, if you load an image, an `ndarray` is returned.

`array[i,j]` gives you the pixel value at (i,j) position.

Also, for imageROI, array slicing can be used like `ROI=array[c1:c2,r1:r2]`. No need of separate functions.

To add two images, there isn't a need to call any function, just do `res = img1+img2`. (But NumPy addition is a modulo operation for uint8 arrays like images. See the article *[Difference between Matrix Arithmetic in OpenCV and Numpy](http://opencvpython.blogspot.in/2012/06/difference-between-matrix-arithmetic-in.html)* to know more.

Contours returned are lists of Numpy arrays. You can find a detailed discussion about Contours in *[Contours - 1 : Getting Started](http://opencvpython.blogspot.in/2012/06/hi-this-article-is-tutorial-which-try.html)*.

***In short, with cv2 everything is simplified and pretty fast.***

A simple discussion on how NumPy speed up `cv2` is in Stack Overflow question *[Performance comparison of OpenCV-Python interfaces, cv and cv2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357696)*.

**pyopencv**:

I don't know much about this since I haven't used it. But it seems to have stopped further development.

I think it would be better to stick on to official libraries.

***In short, I would recommend you to use cv2!***

EDIT: You can see installation procedure for the `cv2` module in *[Install OpenCV in Windows for Python](http://opencvpython.blogspot.in/2012/05/install-opencv-in-windows-for-python.html)*.

Comment: cv2 Python interface will be compiled and installed if you are building OpenCV from the sources. If you are using binary packages for Linux or other OS you should consult your OS/distribution documentation. See http://goo.gl/MUjXi for help.

Comment: @Framester: see installation procedure for cv2 in this link : http://opencvpython.blogspot.in/2012/05/install-opencv-in-windows-for-python.html

Comment: Abid's answer is great. Just to add one more point: I did [a project with Python 3.x](https://github.com/kobejohn/PQUtility) and the only way I could get access to opencv was through ctypes_opencv and the original OpenCV 1.0. It claims support for OpenCV pre1.1 but I never got it working. With that, you will be using the original cvSetROI, etc. C-type interface.

Comment: If you want to install it with pip. read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51853018/how-do-i-install-opencv-using-pip) or do: `pip install opencv-python`