# Python OpenCV Box2D

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv

I am trying to call OpenCV function MinAreaRect2 from within python.
I use OpenCV 2.4.2 with python 2.7 and numpy 1.6.
I went this far :

```
import cv

def nda2ipl(arr, dtype=None):
    return cv.fromarray(np.ascontiguousarray(arr, dtype=dtype))

def min_area_rect2(points):
    storage = cv.CreateMemStorage()
    cv_points = nda2ipl(points.reshape((-1, 1, 2)))
    out = cv.MinAreaRect2(cv_points, storage)
return out
```

I can call this function with a ndarray of shape (N x 2). I get this kind of results :

```
((476.5, 604.5), (951.0, 1207.0), -0.0)
```

I assume that the first tuple is the center of the box, the second gives the width and the height and the last is the angle.

The problem is I could not get a clear reference stating this. Actually, the opencv documentation tells me what the functions returns in Python.

I found the [official documentation about this function](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=minarearect#cv.MinAreaRect2) but this is not very helpful.

What are exactly the output of MinAreaRect2 in python ?
More generally, where do you get precise documentation about the OpenCV python wrapper ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OpenCV Python wrapper documentation is kept along with the normal documentation in same site, [www.docs.opencv.org](http://www.docs.opencv.org)

Earlier Python module used was `cv` interface, which used native data types from original C++ interface like cvMat, cvSeq etc.

Later it was shifted to more better, advanced and simpler module `cv2` interface. In it, everything is returned as either Numpy arrays or native python data types.

Here, tuple returned has the same arguments as that of **[cvBox2D](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/old_basic_structures.html?highlight=box2d#cvbox2d)**. You can find more details the differences between different python wrappers here : [What is different between all these OpenCV Python interfaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10417108/what-is-different-between-all-these-opencv-python-interfaces/10425504#10425504)

Here, your assumption is correct. Those values specified exactly what you mentioned.

If you want to draw rotated rect, you need 4 vertices of the rectangle. For that, you need a function which is never seen in documentation, ie **cv2.cv.BoxPoints()** (but don't worry, it will be there in documentation when OpenCV 2.4.3 is released. )

[image]

Comment: Somehow disappointing, it seems they have [postponed](http://code.opencv.org/issues/2023) your request for adding BoxPoints to documentation, until OpenCV 3.0

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the documentation to which you linked, MinAreaRect2 returns a [Box2D object](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=minarearect2#cv.MinAreaRect2):

A CvBox2D object is defined by its center, size and angle, as you correctly assumed, as described [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/old_basic_structures.html?highlight=cvbox2d#CvBox2D).

Generally speaking, the documentation of the Python wrapper is rather poor. Your best bet is to refer to the C++ documentation and to read the source code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the python function does not return a Box2D object but a python tuple. So I wondered about the relation between the tuple elements and the C++ Box2D struct. I tried looking at the source code but could not find a place which could give me the answer. I have difficulties understanding how the opencv library is wrapped into python, actually. Any hint about this would be very welcomed.

Comment: I found this post quite clarifying: http://opencvpython.blogspot.com.es/2012/06/contours-2-brotherhood.html