# OpenCV Python: Draw minAreaRect ( RotatedRect not implemented)

Tags: python, opencv

Are there any helper methods to draw a rotated rectangle that is returned by [cv2.minAreaRect()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=minarearect#cv2.minAreaRect) presumably as `((x1,y1),(x2,y2),angle)`? [cv2.rectangle()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#rectangle) does not support an angle.
And since the tuple returned is not of the "RotatedRect" class (because it seems to not be implemented in the Python bindings) there is no `points()` method, as shown in the C++ tutorial ["Creating Bounding rotated boxes and ellipses for contours¶"](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/bounding_rotated_ellipses/bounding_rotated_ellipses.html#bounding-rotated-ellipses).

How could a rotated rectangle be drawn from lines - rotate about the center point or the first point given?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

```py
rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)
box = cv2.boxPoints(rect) # cv2.cv.BoxPoints(rect) for OpenCV <3.x
box = np.int0(box)
cv2.drawContours(im,[box],0,(0,0,255),2)
```

should do the trick.

sources:

1. http://opencvpython.blogspot.in/2012/06/contours-2-brotherhood.html
2. [Python OpenCV Box2D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779100/python-opencv-box2d)

Comment: @handle: Additional information for future readers: The above answer is best option with OpenCV 2.4.x version. OpenCV 3.x is about to be released soon. It has a function ``cv2.boxPoints(rect)`` for the same. ``cv2.cv.BoxPoints(rect)`` will be removed then.

Comment: for those who are not using "minAreaRect" function, you can do a custom rotated rectangle structure as "rot_rect = ((x, y), (width, height), angle)"

Comment: What does `box = np.int0(box)` line do?

Comment: @csg it converts the values of `box` to integers

Answer (score 11):

In extension to Tobias Hermann's answer: in case you don't have a contour, but a rotated rectangle defined by its center point, dimensions and angle:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# given your rotated rectangle is defined by variables used below

rect = ((center_x, center_y), (dim_x, dim_y), angle)
box = cv2.cv.BoxPoints(rect) # cv2.boxPoints(rect) for OpenCV 3.x
box = np.int0(box)
cv2.drawContours(im,[box],0,(0,0,255),2)
```

Comment: `rect = ((center_x, center_y), (dim_x, dim_y), angle)`
That's a really great information. Thank you for this.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a concrete example to draw the rotated rectangle. The idea is to obtain a binary image with [Otsu's threshold](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html#otsus-binarization) then find contours using [`cv2.findContours()`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours). We can obtain the rotated rectangle using `cv2.minAreaRect()` and the four corner vertices using `cv2.boxPoints()`. To draw the rectangle we can use [`cv2.drawContours()`](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_begin/py_contours_begin.html) or `cv2.polylines()`.

---

Input `->` Output

[image]
[image]

Code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image, convert to grayscale, Otsu's threshold for binary image
image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Find contours, find rotated rectangle, obtain four verticies, and draw 
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnts[0])
box = np.int0(cv2.boxPoints(rect))
cv2.drawContours(image, [box], 0, (36,255,12), 3) # OR
# cv2.polylines(image, [box], True, (36,255,12), 3)

cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: If you mind please tell me how to use minAreaRect in cpp.

Comment: This code runs but only seems to draw a single point when calling drawContours. How to get it to draw the entire set of points?

Answer (score 7):

I know this was asked long ago, but I would like to share a different approach as the one proposed by the accepted answer, maybe this could be helpful for someone else (actually this has been done before in C++, but it seems python still lacks of [RotatedRect](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.2/db/dd6/classcv_1_1RotatedRect.html) class).

The idea is to define a rotated rectangle from an angle, a size (W and H) and an initial point. This initial point is the relative top-left corner (the top-left corner of the same size rectangle with no rotation angle). From here, the four vertices can be obtained, which allows us to draw the rotated rectangle with four lines.

```
class RRect:
  def __init__(self, p0, s, ang):
    self.p0 = (int(p0[0]),int(p0[1]))
    (self.W, self.H) = s
    self.ang = ang
    self.p1,self.p2,self.p3 = self.get_verts(p0,s[0],s[1],ang)
    self.verts = [self.p0,self.p1,self.p2,self.p3]

  def get_verts(self, p0, W, H, ang):
    sin = numpy.sin(ang/180*3.14159)
    cos = numpy.cos(ang/180*3.14159)
    P1 = (int(self.H*sin)+p0[0],int(self.H*cos)+p0[1])
    P2 = (int(self.W*cos)+P1[0],int(-self.W*sin)+P1[1])
    P3 = (int(self.W*cos)+p0[0],int(-self.W*sin)+p0[1])
    return [P1,P2,P3]

  def draw(self, image):
    print(self.verts)
    for i in range(len(self.verts)-1):
      cv2.line(image, (self.verts[i][0], self.verts[i][1]), (self.verts[i+1][0],self.verts[i+1][1]), (0,255,0), 2)
    cv2.line(image, (self.verts[3][0], self.verts[3][1]), (self.verts[0][0], self.verts[0][1]), (0,255,0), 2)

(W, H) = (30,60)
ang = 35 #degrees
P0 = (50,50)
rr = RRect(P0,(W,H),ang)
rr.draw(image)
cv2.imshow("Text Detection", image)
cv2.waitKey(200)
```

I guess, a similar approach can be used to define the rotated rectangle in terms of its center instead of its relative top-left initial point, but I haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @[smajtks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2836854/smajtkst)'s answer I define the rotated rectangle in terms of its center instead of its relative top-left initial point. Here is the code:

```
class RRect_center:
  def __init__(self, p0, s, ang):
    (self.W, self.H) = s # rectangle width and height
    self.d = math.sqrt(self.W**2 + self.H**2)/2.0 # distance from center to vertices    
    self.c = (int(p0[0]+self.W/2.0),int(p0[1]+self.H/2.0)) # center point coordinates
    self.ang = ang # rotation angle
    self.alpha = math.radians(self.ang) # rotation angle in radians
    self.beta = math.atan2(self.H, self.W) # angle between d and horizontal axis
    # Center Rotated vertices in image frame
    self.P0 = (int(self.c[0] - self.d * math.cos(self.beta - self.alpha)), int(self.c[1] - self.d * math.sin(self.beta-self.alpha))) 
    self.P1 = (int(self.c[0] - self.d * math.cos(self.beta + self.alpha)), int(self.c[1] + self.d * math.sin(self.beta+self.alpha))) 
    self.P2 = (int(self.c[0] + self.d * math.cos(self.beta - self.alpha)), int(self.c[1] + self.d * math.sin(self.beta-self.alpha))) 
    self.P3 = (int(self.c[0] + self.d * math.cos(self.beta + self.alpha)), int(self.c[1] - self.d * math.sin(self.beta+self.alpha))) 

    self.verts = [self.P0,self.P1,self.P2,self.P3]

  def draw(self, image):
    # print(self.verts)
    for i in range(len(self.verts)-1):
      cv2.line(image, (self.verts[i][0], self.verts[i][1]), (self.verts[i+1][0],self.verts[i+1][1]), (0,255,0), 2)
    cv2.line(image, (self.verts[3][0], self.verts[3][1]), (self.verts[0][0], self.verts[0][1]), (0,255,0), 2)

(W, H) = (30,60)
ang = 35 #degrees
P0 = (50,50)
rr = RRect_center(P0,(W,H),ang)
rr.draw(image)
cv2.imshow("Text Detection", image)
cv2.waitKey(200
```

Here, the rectangle is rotated around its center, not from the initial point P0.