# How can I use RotatedRect in Python in order to use it for ellipse?

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to implement in python the following C++ code

```
cv::RotatedRect box1(center, cv::Size(a_axis, b_axis), 0);
cv::ellipse(*img, box1, cv::Scalar(255, 255, 0), 1);
```

I know that ellipse would be

```
   image = cv.ellipse(image, box, (255,255,0), 1)
```

but how do I get the box (RotatedRect)?

Comment: Are you asking about `RotatedRect` in general or about `RotatedRect` with `angle=0` as in your C++ code sample?

Comment: In Python it's a tuple of the 3 components you pass to the `RotatedRect` in C++, in the same order. Or just use the [overload of `cv.ellipse`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.5/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga28b2267d35786f5f890ca167236cbc69), which instead of `RotatedRect` takes the 3 components separately....

Answer (score 0):

`RotatedRect` implementation works properly only on c++. Have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60509877/opencvs-rotatedrect-has-no-attribute-size-in-python3-how-to-work-around-this).
Also have a look at the answers and comments of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18207181/opencv-python-draw-minarearect-rotatedrect-not-implemented) for more discussion on the workaround.