# Why i can't correctly select the rectangular areas with java opencv?

Tags: java, opencv, computer-vision, edge-detection

through opencv I would like to select the areas of the receipts from images like this:

https://i.imgur.com/BnXzWPe.jpg

and then crop them and save them in separate files.

The image was scanned at 1200 Dpi by superimposing a black cardboard over the receipts to better identify the edges.

So far I have come to the following result:

https://i.imgur.com/tRaPocd.jpg

where you can see in red the bounding box rectangle containing the receipt and in green the rectangle with the minimum area.

Despite the correct identification of the edges with Canny:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aULhG.jpg

the central image green area is not correct and I cannot understand why.

This is an excerpt from the source code that you can find here in full: https://pastebin.com/NNc18pzA

```
Imgproc.resize (srcMat, srcMat, new Size (0,0), 0.5, 0.5, Imgproc.INTER_AREA);
Imgproc.cvtColor (srcMat, grayMat, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
Imgproc.threshold (grayMat, grayMat, 177, 200, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);
Imgproc.GaussianBlur (grayMat, blurredMat, new Size (21,21), 0, 0, Core.BORDER_DEFAULT); // 3,3, 9,9 15,15, ....

Mat rectKernel = Imgproc.getStructuringElement (Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, new Size (21,21));

Imgproc.dilate (blurredMat, dilatedMat, rectKernel, new Point (0,0), 1);
Imgproc.Canny (dilatedMat, cannyMat, 100,200.3);

List <MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList <MatOfPoint> ();
final Mat hierarchy = new Mat ();

Imgproc.findContours (cannyMat, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_TREE, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
```

These are the images processed in the intermediate stages:

grayed:
https://i.imgur.com/ufeIMQT.jpg

blurred:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2M6GW.jpg

dilated:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPlj4.jpg

this is the version of opencv used:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openpnp</groupId>
    <artifactId>opencv</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0-2</version>
</dependency>
```

Please help me.

Thank you all.

Comment: After posting the answer, I tried your JAVA code, and the problem is not reproducible (I downloaded the JAVA code only now). I saw you replaced `200.3` with `200,3`. Did you fix the issue, or is it a result of using different OpenCV version? I also updated my post with suggested simplified version of JAVA implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is applying `findContours` after Canny edge detection.

The Canny operator creates small gaps in the external contours:
[image]

In combination with `approxPolyDP`, we are getting weird results.

---

Simple solution is skipping the Canny operator and applying `findContours` on `dilatedMat`.

Replace `Imgproc.findContours(cannyMat, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_TREE, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);` with:

```
Imgproc.findContours(dilatedMat, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
```

Note: using `RETR_EXTERNAL` is recommended but not a must in this case.

---

A minor issue is that there are small contours that are result of noise.
We may use [opening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opening_(morphology)) morphological operation for removing the small (noise) contours (better applied before dilate).

Another simple solution is skipping contours with small area.
I found out that area below 10000 pixels may considered "small".

In the for loop add an if statement:

```
double area = Imgproc.contourArea(cnt);
if (area > 10000) { // Exclude small contours (noise)...
```

---

Output:

[image]

---

I converted the code to Python (the JAVA code is kept in the comments).

Complete code sample:

```python
import cv2
import numpy as np

srcMat = cv2.imread('receipts.jpg')  # Read input image
cv2.resize(srcMat, (0, 0), srcMat, 0.1, 0.1, cv2.INTER_AREA)  # Imgproc.resize (srcMat, srcMat, new Size (0,0), 0.5, 0.5, Imgproc.INTER_AREA);
grayMat = cv2.cvtColor(srcMat, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  # grayMat = Imgproc.cvtColor (srcMat, grayMat, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
grayMat = cv2.threshold(grayMat, 177, 200, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]  # Imgproc.threshold (grayMat, grayMat, 177, 200, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);
blurredMat = cv2.GaussianBlur(grayMat, ksize=(21, 21), sigmaX=0, sigmaY=0)  # Imgproc.GaussianBlur (grayMat, blurredMat, new Size (21,21), 0, 0, Core.BORDER_DEFAULT); // 3,3, 9,9 15,15, ....

rectKernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (21, 21))  # Mat rectKernel = Imgproc.getStructuringElement (Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, new Size (21,21));

dilatedMat = cv2.dilate(blurredMat, rectKernel)  # Imgproc.dilate (blurredMat, dilatedMat, rectKernel, new Point (0,0), 1);
cannyMat = cv2.Canny(dilatedMat, 100, 200.3)  # Imgproc.Canny (dilatedMat, cannyMat, 100,200.3);

# List <MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList <MatOfPoint> ();
# final Mat hierarchy = new Mat ();
#contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(cannyMat, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)  # Imgproc.findContours(cannyMat, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_TREE, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

# Find contours over dilatedMat (the Canny operator creates gaps in the external contour).
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dilatedMat, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)  # Imgproc.findContours(dilatedMat, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);


# Use cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL instead of cv2.RETR_TREE
#contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(cannyMat, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)  # Imgproc.findContours(cannyMat, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_TREE, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

cntImg = srcMat.copy()
# Mark best_cnt with green line - used for testing
cv2.drawContours(cntImg, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 20)

# for(MatOfPoint cnt : contours) {
for cnt  in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)

    # Exclude small contours (noise)
    if area > 10000:
        mop2f = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.02 * cv2.arcLength(cnt, True), True)  # Imgproc.approxPolyDP(mop2f, mop2f, 0.02*Imgproc.arcLength(mop2f, true), true);
        rr = cv2.minAreaRect(mop2f) #  RotatedRect rr = Imgproc.minAreaRect(mop2f);
        m = cv2.boxPoints(rr) # Imgproc.boxPoints(rr, m);  

        # Point[] rectPoints = new Point[4];
        # rr.points(rectPoints);
        rectPoints = np.int0(m)  # Convert all coordinates floating point values to int

        # for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
        #     Imgproc.line(srcMat, rectPoints[j], rectPoints[(j + 1) % 4], new Scalar(0,255,0), 20); }    
        #for j in range(4):
        #    cv2.line(srcMat, tuple(rectPoints[j]), tuple(rectPoints[(j + 1) % 4]), (0, 255, 0), 20)  # Imgproc.line(srcMat, rectPoints[j], rectPoints[(j + 1) % 4], new Scalar(0,255,0), 20);

        # Deaw the rectangles using drawContours instead of drawing lines
        # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18207181/opencv-python-draw-minarearect-rotatedrect-not-implemented
        cv2.drawContours(srcMat, [rectPoints], 0, (0, 255, 0), 20)

        boundingRect = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)  # Rect boundingRect = Imgproc.boundingRect(cnt);
        cv2.rectangle(srcMat, boundingRect, (0, 0, 255), 20)  # Imgproc.rectangle(srcMat, boundingRect, new Scalar(0,0,255),20); //scalar not is RGB but BGR !
```

---

Simplifying the implementation (suggestion):

- Use `Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU` for automatic threshold selection.
- There is no need to apply `GaussianBlur`.
- Use closing instead of dilate.
- There is no need to apply `Canny`.

Suggested JAVA code:

```
package myproject; //package it.neo7bf;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint2f;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.core.Rect;
import org.opencv.core.RotatedRect;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.core.Size;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

//import nu.pattern.OpenCV;

public class SeparationTest3 {
    
    static { System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME); }
    
    static class I {
        public String name;
        public int v;
        I(String name, int v) {
            this.name = name;
            this.v = v;
        }
    }
    
    public static void cannyTest() {

        List<I> images = List.of(
            new I("2022-04-16_085329",3)
        );

        for(I image : images) {

            Mat srcMat = Imgcodecs.imread("C:\\ProgettoScontrino\\scontrini\\campioni-test\\test-separazione\\"+image.name+".jpg");
            
            Mat grayMat = new Mat();
            //Mat blurredMat = new Mat();
            Mat dilatedMat = new Mat();
            //Mat cannyMat = new Mat();
            

            Imgproc.resize(srcMat, srcMat, new Size(0,0), 0.5, 0.5, Imgproc.INTER_AREA);
            Imgproc.cvtColor(srcMat, grayMat, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
            //Imgproc.threshold(grayMat, grayMat, 177, 200, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);
            Imgproc.threshold(grayMat, grayMat, 0, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU);  //Use automatic threshold
            
            //There is no need to blur the image after threshold
            //Imgproc.GaussianBlur(grayMat, blurredMat, new Size(21,21),0, 0,Core.BORDER_DEFAULT); //3,3, 9,9 15,15,....
                
            Mat rectKernel = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, new Size(21,21));
            
            //Imgproc.dilate(blurredMat, dilatedMat, rectKernel, new Point(0,0),1);
            Imgproc.morphologyEx(grayMat, dilatedMat, Imgproc.MORPH_CLOSE, rectKernel);  // Use closing instead of dilate
            //Imgproc.Canny(dilatedMat,cannyMat,100,200,3); //No need for Canny
            
            List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
            final Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
    
            //Imgproc.findContours(cannyMat, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_TREE, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
            
            Imgproc.findContours(dilatedMat, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
            
            //contours = getMaxContours(contours,image.v);
            
            for(MatOfPoint cnt : contours) {
                double area = Imgproc.contourArea(cnt);
                if (area > 10000) //Ignore small contours
                {
                    MatOfPoint2f mop2f = new MatOfPoint2f(cnt.toArray());
                    Imgproc.approxPolyDP(mop2f, mop2f, 0.02*Imgproc.arcLength(mop2f, true), true);
                    RotatedRect rr = Imgproc.minAreaRect(mop2f);
                    MatOfPoint m = new MatOfPoint();                    
                    Imgproc.boxPoints(rr, m);
                    Point[] rectPoints = new Point[4];          
                    rr.points(rectPoints);
                    for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
                      Imgproc.line(srcMat, rectPoints[j], rectPoints[(j + 1) % 4], new Scalar(0,255,0), 20); 
                    }

                    //BoundingBox
                    Rect boundingRect = Imgproc.boundingRect(cnt);
                    Imgproc.rectangle(srcMat, boundingRect, new Scalar(0,0,255),20); //scalar not is RGB but BGR !
                }
            }
                    
            //C:\ProgettoScontrino\scontrini\campioni-test\test-separazione\output\
            Imgcodecs.imwrite("C:\\ProgettoScontrino\\scontrini\\campioni-test\\test-separazione\\output\\"+image.name+"gray.jpg", grayMat);
            //Imgcodecs.imwrite("C:\\ProgettoScontrino\\scontrini\\campioni-test\\test-separazione\\output\\"+image.name+"blurred.jpg", blurredMat);
            Imgcodecs.imwrite("C:\\ProgettoScontrino\\scontrini\\campioni-test\\test-separazione\\output\\"+image.name+"dilated.jpg", dilatedMat);
            //Imgcodecs.imwrite("C:\\ProgettoScontrino\\scontrini\\campioni-test\\test-separazione\\output\\"+image.name+"canny.jpg", cannyMat);
            Imgcodecs.imwrite("C:\\ProgettoScontrino\\scontrini\\campioni-test\\test-separazione\\output\\"+image.name+"contours.jpg", srcMat);
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        cannyTest();
    }
}
```