# How to get a color range from a "Drag Box" in OpenCV 2.4

Tags: opencv, python-2.7

I'm using Python and OpenCV 2.4. I'm trying to get a HSV average from an area selected by dragging the mouse, much like in the [camShift](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/python2/camshift.py) example provided by OpenCV.  But I want the X, Y of the selected color instances in a video feed.

I've been hacking at the onmouse function in camShift.  I feel it is close to want I want, I just can't seem to extract the mean HSV values of the area selected. I know I could probably get this done with a for loop, but trying to make it as responsive as possible.

```
def onmouse(self, event, x, y, flags, param):
    x, y = np.int16([x, y]) # BUG
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        self.drag_start = (x, y)
        self.tracking_state = 0
    if self.drag_start:
        if flags & cv2.EVENT_FLAG_LBUTTON:
            h, w = 480, 640 # self.frame.shape[:2]
            xo, yo = self.drag_start
            x0, y0 = np.maximum(0, np.minimum([xo, yo], [x, y]))
            x1, y1 = np.minimum([w, h], np.maximum([xo, yo], [x, y]))
            self.selection = None
            if x1-x0 > 0 and y1-y0 > 0:
                self.selection = (x0, y0, x1, y1)
        else:
            self.drag_start = None
            if self.selection is not None:
                self.tracking_state = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok.  It's crude, but this seems to be a lot closer than  I was:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import video


class App(object):
    def __init__(self, video_src):
        #self.cam = video.create_capture(video_src)
        self.cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        ret, self.frame = self.cam.read()
        cv2.namedWindow('camshift')
        cv2.setMouseCallback('camshift', self.onmouse)

        self.selection = None
        self.drag_start = None
        self.tracking_state = 0
        self.show_backproj = False

    def onmouse(self, event, x, y, flags, param):
        x, y = np.int16([x, y]) # BUG
        if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
            self.drag_start = (x, y)
            self.tracking_state = 0
        if self.drag_start:
            if flags & cv2.EVENT_FLAG_LBUTTON:
                h, w = self.frame.shape[:2]
                xo, yo = self.drag_start
                x0, y0 = np.maximum(0, np.minimum([xo, yo], [x, y]))
                x1, y1 = np.minimum([w, h], np.maximum([xo, yo], [x, y]))
                self.selection = None
                if x1-x0 > 0 and y1-y0 > 0:
                    self.selection = (x0, y0, x1, y1)
            else:
                self.drag_start = None
                if self.selection is not None:
                    self.tracking_state = 1

    def show_hist(self):
        bin_count = self.hist.shape[0]
        bin_w = 24
        img = np.zeros((256, bin_count*bin_w, 3), np.uint8)
        for i in xrange(bin_count):
            h = int(self.hist[i])
            cv2.rectangle(img, (i*bin_w+2, 255), ((i+1)*bin_w-2, 255-h), (int(180.0*i/bin_count), 255, 255), -1)
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
        cv2.imshow('hist', img)

    def run(self):
        while True:

            ret, self.frame = self.cam.read()
            self.frame = cv2.blur(self.frame,(3,3))
            vis = self.frame.copy()
            hsv = cv2.cvtColor(self.frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
            mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, np.array((0., 60., 32.)), np.array((180., 255., 255.)))
            mask2 = mask.copy()

            if self.selection:
                x0, y0, x1, y1 = self.selection
                self.track_window = (x0, y0, x1-x0, y1-y0)
                hsv_roi = hsv[y0:y1, x0:x1]
                mask_roi = mask[y0:y1, x0:x1]
                #cv2.norm(hsv_roi)
                dHSV = cv2.mean(hsv_roi)
                h, s, v = int(dHSV[0]), int(dHSV[1]), int(dHSV[2])
                hist = cv2.calcHist( [hsv_roi], [0], mask_roi, [16], [0, 180] )

                cv2.normalize(hist, hist, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX);
                self.hist = hist.reshape(-1)
                self.show_hist()
                vis_roi = vis[y0:y1, x0:x1]
                cv2.bitwise_not(vis_roi, vis_roi)
                vis[mask == 0] = 0

            if self.tracking_state == 1:
                self.selection = None

            cv2.imshow('camshift', vis)
            if self.tracking_state == 1:
                if h > 159:
                    h = 159
                if s > 235:
                    s = 235
                if v > 235:
                    v = 235

                if h < 20:
                    h = 20
                if s < 20:
                    s = 20
                if v < 20:
                    v = 20

                thresh = cv2.inRange(hsv,np.array(((h-20), (s-20), (v-20))), np.array(((h+20), (s+20), (v+20))))
                thresh2 = thresh.copy()

                # find contours in the threshold image
                contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

                #best_cnt = 1 
                max_area = 0
                for cnt in contours:
                    area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
                    if area > max_area:
                        max_area = area
                        best_cnt = cnt

                # finding centroids of best_cnt and draw a circle there
                M = cv2.moments(best_cnt)
                cx,cy = int(M['m10']/M['m00']), int(M['m01']/M['m00'])

                print cx, cy
                cv2.circle(thresh2,(cx,cy),20,255,-1)
                cv2.imshow('thresh',thresh2)


            ch = 0xFF & cv2.waitKey(5)
            if ch == 27:
                break
            if ch == ord('b'):
                self.show_backproj = not self.show_backproj
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    try: video_src = sys.argv[1]
    except: video_src = 0
    print __doc__
    App(video_src).run()
```

I hack-sawed [Rahman's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12943410/opencv-python-single-rather-than-multiple-blob-tracking) example and [camShift](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/python2/camshift.py)