# Difference between numpy.uint8 and numpy.int8 in openCV?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, image-editing

I want the output window with a green square at the center.

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

blank = np.zeros((500, 500, 3), dtype=np.int8)
blank[200:300, 200:300] = 0, 255, 0
cv.imshow('Blank', blank)
cv.waitKey(0)
```

This is showing me just a grey background but not a green square in the center but if I change
`dtype=np.int8` -> `dtype=np.uint8` I'm getting what I want.

So I just want to know the difference between `dtype=np.int8` and `dtype=np.uint8`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "u" in "uint" is short for "unsigned", meaning the integer doesn't have a sign (it can't be negative).

Signed 8 bit integers values go from -128 to +127, while unsigned go from 0 to 255 : The classic "byte"

Comment: It means the above code will work only if RGB values lie between (-127) - (+127).

Answer (score 0):

Talking about **CV2** see [What is different between all these OpenCV Python interfaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10417108/what-is-different-between-all-these-opencv-python-interfaces)

> All the OpenCV Python array structures are converted to and from Numpy arrays.

A list of Numpy Array types and conversions between types can be found in relevant
documentation pages : [Data types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69422392/opencv-unsupported-depth-of-input-image-depth-is-3-cv-16s-when-using-cv2-cv)

```
numpy.uint8[source]
numpy.uint16
numpy.uint32
numpy.uint64

    Alias for the unsigned integer types (one of numpy.byte, numpy.short,
 numpy.intc, numpy.int_ and numpy.longlong) with the specified number of bits.

    Compatible with the C99 uint8_t, uint16_t, uint32_t, and uint64_t, respectively.
```

As for their values :

unsigned integer values:

The number of bits determines directly the range for the respective values,

here in Decimal notation :

```
Number of bits Min. value Max. value

8 bit              0        255

16 bit             0        65535

32 bit             0        4294967295

64 bit             0        2^64 - 1
```

---

```
numpy.int8[source]
numpy.int16
numpy.int32
numpy.int64

    Aliases for the signed integer types (one of numpy.byte, numpy.short, 
numpy.intc, numpy.int_ and numpy.longlong) with the specified number of bits.

    Compatible with the C99 int8_t, int16_t, int32_t, and int64_t, respectively.
```

same as above but signed so :

```
Number of bits         Min. value    Max. value

int8                         -128    127

int16                     -32,768    32,767
    
int32              -2,147,483,648    2,147,483,647
    
int64  -9,223,372,036,854,775,808    9,223,372,036,854,775,807
```

Then of course :

What data types are supported by OpenCV?
Data types

```
schar - signed 1 byte integer.
uchar - unsigned 1 byte integer.
short - signed 2 byte integer.
ushort - unsigned 2 byte integer.
int - signed 4 byte integer.
uint - unsigned 4 byte integer.
int64 - signed 8 byte integer.
uint64 - unsigned 8 byte integer.
```

1 byte = 8 bit

but then [OpenCV unsupported depth of input image, 'depth' is 3 (CV_16S) when using cv2.cvtColor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69422392/opencv-unsupported-depth-of-input-image-depth-is-3-cv-16s-when-using-cv2-cv) :

```
cvtColor complains because the data has the wrong dtype.

Your data has dtype int16 (signed integer).

cvtColor only accepts uint8, uint16, and float32. Those are CV_8U, CV_16U, and CV_32F in OpenCV parlance, which have the numerical values 0, 2, 5.

Solution: use a supported dtype. It seems that skvideo.io.vread already returns data in uint8. Just drop the superfluous np.array(..., dtype=np.int16) around it.
```

......