# OpenCV unsupported depth of input image, 'depth' is 3 (CV_16S) when using cv2.cvtColor

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, scikit-image

I'm reading in a video file and convert it to a numpy array.

like so:

```
video= np.array(skvideo.io.vread(folder + "video.avi"), dtype=np.int16)
```

later I access the first frame and save it under img

```
img = video[0]
```

the shape now has 3 channels:

```
389, 516, 3
```

When converting to grayscale:

```
gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

I get this error:

```
error: OpenCV(4.1.2) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.simd_helpers.hpp:94: error: (-2:Unspecified error) in function 'cv::impl::{anonymous}::CvtHelper<VScn, VDcn, VDepth, sizePolicy>::CvtHelper(cv::InputArray, cv::OutputArray, int) [with VScn = cv::impl::{anonymous}::Set<3, 4>; VDcn = cv::impl::{anonymous}::Set<1>; VDepth = cv::impl::{anonymous}::Set<0, 2, 5>; cv::impl::{anonymous}::SizePolicy sizePolicy = (cv::impl::<unnamed>::SizePolicy)2u; cv::InputArray = const cv::_InputArray&; cv::OutputArray = const cv::_OutputArray&]'
> Unsupported depth of input image:
>     'VDepth::contains(depth)'
> where
>     'depth' is 3 (CV_16S)
```

The video and images display fine.
I actually got to this error because I wanted to plot histograms and I get an error with no documentation when passing the first frame.

Is it possible that I have to use `cv2.VideoCapture`?
I don't see how this should be the case as it's a perfectly fine numpy array.

thank you for your help!

Comment: try using `dtype=np.uint8` for the video array, opencv doesn't support all data types

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cvtColor` complains because the data has the wrong `dtype`.

Your data has `dtype` `int16` (signed integer).

`cvtColor` only accepts `uint8`, `uint16`, and `float32`. Those are `CV_8U`, `CV_16U`, and `CV_32F` in OpenCV parlance, which have the numerical values `0, 2, 5`.

Solution: use a supported dtype. It seems that `skvideo.io.vread` already returns data in `uint8`. Just drop the superfluous `np.array(..., dtype=np.int16)` around it.

Comment: Thanks Christoph I will try that, @Dominik Ficek's worked as well. I only got the above working with another library if I changed dtype to int16, that's why it was there.

Answer (score 0):

Weirdly, it does work if I read in the video with video capture and then iterate over the frames.

So one solution to above is

```
video= cv2.VideoCapture(folder + 'video.avi')
is_true, frame = video.read()
```

then do the rest as before.

If someone could explain why (what the difference between the arrays is) that'd be great.

Comment: yea it works, beause it's NOT converting to something silly.

Comment: converting later on works that's what I meant. @berak

Comment: well, your earlier conversion was the error (and looks like "blind copypasting")

Comment: @berak of course I copy and paste (though I am only able to with my eyes open, have you tried with yours closed?) from docs, SO and elsewhere as should be evident by the codesamples 1:1 correspondency to the documentation I used (otherwise I link).

Comment: verdict still is : you wrongly added a (bad) cast, without knowing (or asking) why