# imread not declared in scope (opencv-ecllipse)

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv

Here is a code. when i try to build it in eclipse it says "imread" and almost all functions are not declared in the scope.

```
    #include <cv.h>
    #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
    #include <highgui.h>

    using namespace cv;

    int main( int argc, char** argv )
    {
      Mat image;
      image = imread( "download.jpg",0 );

      if( argc != 2 || !image.data )
        {
          printf( "No image data \n" );
          return -1;
        }

      namedWindow( "Display Image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
      imshow( "Display Image", image );

      waitKey(0);

      return 0;
    }
```

List of errors are shown below

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
make: *** [src/DisplayImage1.o] Error 1 DisplayImage            C/C++ Problem
make: *** [display] Error 1 display         C/C++ Problem
‘namedWindow’ was not declared in this scope    DisplayImage1.cpp   /DisplayImage/src   line 23 C/C++ Problem
‘imread’ was not declared in this scope DisplayImage1.cpp   /DisplayImage/src   line 15 C/C++ Problem
‘waitKey’ was not declared in this scope    DisplayImage1.cpp   /DisplayImage/src   line 26 C/C++ Problem
‘imshow’ was not declared in this scope DisplayImage1.cpp   /DisplayImage/src   line 24 C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `cvRound'    display     line 929, external location: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/types_c.h  C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `cvRound'    display     line 930, external location: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/types_c.h  C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `cvFree_'    display     line 305, external location: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/core_c.h   C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `cvFree_'    display     line 313, external location: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/core_c.h   C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `cvGetRows'  display     line 382, external location: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/core_c.h   C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `cvGetCols'  display     line 408, external location: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/core_c.h   C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `cvReleaseMat'   display     line 477, external location: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/core_c.h   C/C++ Problem
```

Don't know what to do. Any idea ?? i am running the code in eclipse.Load opencv library to it.i m  Using ubuntu. 
Any help will be appriciated

console message:

```
make all 
Building file: ../src/DisplayImage.cpp
Invoking: Cross G++ Compiler
g++ -I/usr/local/include/opencv -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/DisplayImage.d" -MT"src/DisplayImage.d" -o "src/DisplayImage.o" "../src/DisplayImage.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/DisplayImage.cpp

Building file: ../src/DisplayImage1.cpp
Invoking: Cross G++ Compiler
g++ -I/usr/local/include/opencv -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/DisplayImage1.d" -MT"src/DisplayImage1.d" -o "src/DisplayImage1.o" "../src/DisplayImage1.cpp"
../src/DisplayImage1.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
../src/DisplayImage1.cpp:15:30: error: ‘imread’ was not declared in this scope
   image = imread( argv[1], 1 );
                              ^
../src/DisplayImage1.cpp:23:52: error: ‘namedWindow’ was not declared in this scope
   namedWindow( "Display Image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
                                                    ^
../src/DisplayImage1.cpp:24:34: error: ‘imshow’ was not declared in this scope
   imshow( "Display Image", image );
                                  ^
../src/DisplayImage1.cpp:26:12: error: ‘waitKey’ was not declared in this scope
   waitKey(0);
            ^
make: *** [src/DisplayImage1.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Switch from the Problems tab to the Console tab. You will find better error messages and you will find the commands used to build the project. Check the linker command line to make sure you are linking the opencv library. If you aren't sure, edit your question and paste in the contents of the Console tab.

Comment: Addendum: the first few items in the Problems list are generated by Eclipse itself. You may be able to solve them by reindexing your project. In the Project Explorer pane, Right click the project and select Index->Rebuild from the pop-up menu.

Comment: please see now @user4581301

Comment: and i m linking the right libraries, this code is running without eclipse

Comment: Ha., You're right. I read that backwards. My apologies. The undefined references  were bogus or stale.

Comment: So what should i do

Comment: Are DisplayImage and DisplayImage1 the same code in different files? In other words, one builds and the other doesn't?

Comment: No they are different @user4581301

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved just need to add some libraries in gcc linker path

Comment: can you put a detailed solution because I am getting the same error and can't figure out what to do.

Answer (score 0):

For c/c++:

[How to use code completion into Eclipse with OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9085643/how-to-use-code-completion-into-eclipse-with-opencv)

For Python:

In Eclipse IDE,

**Window** -> **Preferences** -> **PyDev** -> **Interpreters** -> **Python Interpreter** -> **Packages** -> **Manage with pip** -> then type '**install cv**' and click Run

now, open Command Prompt and type

> pip install opencv-python

now restart your IDE.